# For each style SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

Essentially what I want to do in pseudocode is:

```
FOR EACH pig_id IN (SELECT pig_id FROM farm AS f)
BEGIN
-- Do something funky with the f.pig_id, for example
  SELECT bacon, ham, pork, (face + guts + brains + testicles) AS 'sausage'
  FROM farm
  WHERE pig_id = f.pig_id
END
```

The actually interior of the loop is more complex but this simple SELECT statement demonstrates the need to use f.pig_id within the loop FOR EACH pig_id in the farm TABLE. I've looked at CREATE TRIGGER solution but I was hoping for something more simple. I am aware that this is an inefficient query but the project required simplicity and easily human readable queries for non technical people.

EDIT:
It is being used on a small dataset so human readability is a priority over efficiency.

Comment: You are attempting to do something inefficient.  You might have better luck inserting the rows into a temp table, updating as necessary, and then querying the temp table.

Comment: This is sometimes called "RBAR" Row By Agonizing Row.  This is NOT you how you want to start out coding TSQL.

Comment: I'm not really sure why a JOIN (or JOINS) wouldn't suffice - when you see code like this it generally stems from a misunderstanding of SQL and sets!

Comment: @Jamie, the SELECT statement is just an example, the actually interior of the loop has various INSERTS and STORED PROCS

Comment: "interior has various inserts and stored procs".........  That is what makes it scarier.  :<     Please check my "anti-example".  RBAR is a performance killer.

Comment: @granadaCoder, I understand your concern but it's for a small dataset running on a beefy box and it is important that the code is human readable for non technical people.

Comment: @Gregology it sounds like you need to re-engineer things a bit, then. Inserts are fine (you can insert with a select), but calling Stored Procedures multiple times doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Jamie, yeah, I've been thinking about that and I've removed them. I was just being lazy having them within the loop :) Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pig_id unique column(e.g. with data type int) you can use loop without CURSOR

```
DECLARE @id int = (SELECT MIN(pig_id) FROM farm) 
WHILE (@id IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN  
  SELECT bacon, ham, pork, (face + guts + brains + testicles) AS 'sausage'
  FROM farm
  WHERE pig_id = @id

  SELECT @id = MIN(pig_id) FROM farm WHERE pig_id > @Id
END
```

OR

```
DECLARE @id int = 0
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
  SELECT @id = (select min(pig_id) from farm where pig_id > @id)     

  IF @id IS NULL
  BREAK
  ELSE

  SELECT bacon, ham, pork, (face + guts + brains + testicles) AS 'sausage'
  FROM farm
  WHERE pig_id = @id
  CONTINUE
END
```

Comment: Cheers mate, this seemed to be the most elegant solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is CURSOR

Here the [link to MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx), there is simple one all the way at the bottome.

Comment: Cursors are evil, and should only be used at a last, last, last, last resort.

Comment: @granadaCoder I do not disagree, but sometimes are necessary evil, without knowing specifics of app, there might be no other way...

Comment: Maybe it is the only way.  But in the past 10 years since I put out a "no cursor" edict (in my group), I've only had one situation where set-baed code could not be written.  You didn't warn him.  You just gave him the dyn@mite with which to go fishing.  Aka, it is possible to go fishing with dyn@mite, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: I appreciate this discussion, maybe I should have been more descriptive with the particulars. It's a small dataset running on a powerful SQL box with limited dev time, so it might call for a dyn@mite solution :)

Comment: I've heard the same cries before.  Good luck.  But I wouldn't put my name on a cursor based solution ... unless someone put some dyn@mite next to me.  We do what we's gots to do I guess.

Answer (score 1):

***RBAR = BAD.***

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/

Set-based good!

.............................

I've created an ANTI example here:

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/cursors-setbased-and-scalar-udf/

The Anti example is that I show you how to use a cursor, but then I show you how to NOT use a cursor to solve the same problem.

Please, please, please avoid cursors.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do something sophisticated with the values from the first query then you can use cursor.

An example:

```
DECLARE @pig int
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT pig_id FROM farm AS f 

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @pig  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       --Do your thing here....

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @pig  
END  

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, a cursor should do what you want here is a simple example:

```
DECLARE @valueHolder INT

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM MyTable
OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @valueHolder

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @valueHolder

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @valueHolder
END

CLOSE myCursor;
DEALLOCATE myCursor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using a cursor you could just use a counter and a `WHILE` loop:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE #Pig
(
PigId INT
)
INSERT INTO #Pig VALUES
(1),
(3),
(6),
(10)

CREATE TABLE #Farm 
(
PigId INT,
Name VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #Farm VALUES
(1,'michaeljackson'),
(1,'jim'),
(3,'jill'),
(3,'j')
```

Script:

```
SELECT  PigId,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PigId)
INTO    #PigRows
FROM    #Pig


DECLARE @max INT = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM #PigRows)

DECLARE @counter INT = 1
WHILE @counter <= @max
BEGIN

    SELECT Name
    FROM #Farm
    WHERE PigId = @counter

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```